# How to create RegEx with SubMatches of the same Match that capture 2 different types of output?

Tags: json, regex, excel, vba, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to get my Jira data via JSON REST API into **Excel**, i.e. using **VBA**, and I'm parsing JSON output using RegEx. There are plenty of useful tutorials on the web, and after a couple of days I do have more or less working solution I'm happy with, except one minor obstacle. Long story short:

Among many issue fields I need friendly **Assignee name**, but some issues in my projects may be *Unassigned*, that obviously results in **TWO** VERY different kinds of JSON output:

**Unassigned** issue:

`..."assignee":null,"updated"...`

**Assigned** issue:

```
"assignee":{
    "self":...
    <Lots of NOT needed fields here>
    ...
    },
    "displayName":"Doe, John", <-- That's what I need, name only part
    "active":...
    <Lots of NOT needed fields here>
    ...
},
"updated"...
```

Well, I suppose that something like:

`"assignee".*?"displayName":"(.*?)"|"assignee":(.*?),"updated"`

will handle the job by producing TWO possible **Matches**, but... **Is there a way to create RegEx where ANY of output options will result in SubMatches of ONE Match?**

I'm a total newbie to RegEx, so sorry if the wording of my question is silly due to incorrectly used terms. Anyway, I hope the sample part is more or less clear, and I'll be extremely grateful for useful suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an hour of tryouts on regex101 I ended up with the following RegEx:

`"assignee":(null|.*?"displayName":"(.*?)","active")`

Probably it's ugly and may be improved - but it DOES the job, and does NOT ruin in the process the indexes of subsequent Matches in collection, therefore keeping the rest of code working as it is now.

Comment: Anyway, just do not hesitate to provide your brilliant suggestions as answers, and I'll re-accept the best option!